# Why docstring description and comments treated differently in VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Example codes.

```
"""
Something.
"""

# Something.
```

They are formatted like this in my VSCode.

[image]

So far from what I know, both are used as comments and multi-line comments. Having codes with same function but with different colors confuses me. Is this behavior intended? Is there any way I can make both docstring and comment styled in the same color and manner?

I am using the latest VSCode (1.61.1). Some related VSCode plugins are Python and Django Template.

Comment: Did you say you are using python?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot answer the "why" question. But here is how to change the color:

(as I answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47935166/5122657)

Add this to your setting file:

```
<!-- language: json -->
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "textMateRules": [
            {
                "scope":"string.quoted.docstring.multi.python",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#69676c" //change to your preference
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

additional info:
for finding out the scope of other element, you use the command `Developer: Inspect TM Scopes` , as described here https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/pull/29393

more detail:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_customize-a-color-theme