# How to customize docstring color for Python in VSCode's default theme?

Tags: python, colors, visual-studio-code, themes

Could some one explain to me please how to customize docstring color for Python in VSCode's default theme? I want to do it thru User Settings because want to be able to save my config file.

I tried to use "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {} but it affects all strings.

Answer (score 29):

Add this to your setting file:

```
<!-- language: json -->
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "textMateRules": [
            {
                "scope":"string.quoted.docstring.multi.python",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#69676c" //change to your preference
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

additional info:
for finding out the scope of other element, you use the command `Developer: Inspect TM Scopes` , as described here https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/pull/29393

more detail:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_customize-a-color-theme

Comment: I got an followup question: How do I change color for only tripple apostrophe docstrings and keep normal string color for triple quotating sign docstrings?

Comment: @LordWolfenstein Do you mean set the color of the apostrophe separately from the content of the docstring? If so, add this: `{
   "scope": [
    "string.quoted.docstring.multi.python punctuation.definition.string.begin.python",
    "string.quoted.docstring.multi.python punctuation.definition.string.end.python"
   ],
   "settings": {
    "foreground": "#ff0909" //change to your preference
   }
  }`

Answer (score 18):

Adding to Leonard's answer, if you want to change the triple quotes and escapes too, use the below:

```json
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "textMateRules": [
            {           
                "scope": [
                    "string.quoted.docstring.multi.python",
                    "string.quoted.docstring.multi.python punctuation.definition.string.begin.python",
                    "string.quoted.docstring.multi.python punctuation.definition.string.end.python",
                    "string.quoted.docstring.multi.python constant.character.escape.python"
                ],          
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#aab5da" //change to your preference
                }       
            }
        ]
    },
```

Also, I had a hard time finding the user settings file in json format. You can find that by:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> > User Settings > On the open tab level extreme right hand side > Open Settings (JSON) icon *(Hover to know which icon)*

Comment: wow, thank you. this is what i was looking for. work on mac big sur.

Answer (score 3):

Leonard's answer above is perfect.

Just for the googlers in 2020, I would add that the command in Command Palette: `Developer: Inspect TM Scopes` seems to have changed to: `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes`.

This option shows both the standard token types, as well as TextMate scopes.